# Java thread visibility - best practice for visibility without explicit synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, visibility

when having java Threads communicating with each other, but no explicit synchronization is required (so no need to call synchronize on an object to synchronize execution), what is the best practice to ensure proper visibility among involved threads?

For example:

```
class B extends Thread {
     ...
     A instanceOfA = ...;

     B(){
          instanceOfA.registerHandler(new Handler(){
               @Override
               handle(SomeObjectToBeVisibile o){
                  ...
               }
          });
     }
}

class A extends Thread {
     ...
     void registerSomeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethod handler){...}

     void executeHandlers(){
          for(each registered handler){
              handler.handle(instanceOfSomeObjectToBeVisible); 
          }

     }
}
```

If I am not mistaken, there is a potential visibility problem to the handlers "handle" method calls passing some constructed object which then might not be visible the proper way in the receiving thread (stale values, e.g.), right? If yes, how to force visibility without using synchronized?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't extends Thread explicitly. Always create your objects before starting threads around them and you won't multi-threaded issues in their construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't be afraid of synchronization, if the synchronized block is small and fast, which is true in your case, lock-unlock won't cause any problems.

You could use a "lock-free" concurrent data structure, like ConcurrentLinkedQueue. (It is not going to be a lot faster for your case)

EDIT: it looks like you are worrying about the visibility of the argument passed to `handle()`, not handlers themselves.

Comment: Yes, it's about the arguments.

Answer (score 4):

It should be possible to use volatile modifiers, however I'd recommend to use [AtomicReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html)

Also if you're passing an object, which is immutable - then no problem would arise at all, since final fields are guaranteed to be initialized before constructor ends it's execution.

Comment: You mean by making internal fields "final"? No that is not the case. Thanks for the hint using AtomicReference.

Comment: An AtomicReference is simply a wrapper around a volatile variable. If the only concern is visibility then volatile would be enough and (a little) simpler.

Comment: @assylias you are wrong, it is not just a "wrapper", it provides CAS support.

Comment: @jdevelop I know that - what I meant is: if the only concern is visibility, CAS operations are not required and volatile semantics will be sufficient.

Comment: @assylias ah, ok, but I think it's like arrays/collections - use latter, because it will give you extra power when you will need it :)